# c++ - delayed execution of code

Tags: c++, timeout

Let's say we are in a function that gets called whenever a mousebutton is pressed

```
static inline LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(const int code, const WPARAM wParam, const LPARAM lParam){


}
```

I would now like to execute some code, after no button has been pressed for 5 seconds. If after 2 seconds, the user clicks a mousebutton, the "timer" should be reset and wait another 5 seconds.

Can this even be done in C++? If I use `Sleep(5000)`, I cannot prevent the code from running if another button is pressed in between.

Comment: 1. Don't block execution. 2. Start/reset counter after mouse click. 3. When button pressed, check if the counter is below five seconds and respond accordingly. 4. After 5 seconds stop counter and set to zero.
Wouldn't this approach be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my class (it's not perfect but you can look how it could be done) to control heartbeat of program behind the socket. When beat() method is called, timer is "reseted".

```
    class HeartbeatController
    {
    private:
        using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    public:
        HeartbeatController(std::function<void()> &heartbeatLostCallback, 
                            const ms &panicTime = ms{5000}, //time in milliseconds, after which panic code will be executed
                            const ms &checkDuration = ms{ 1000 }) noexcept :
            heartbeatLostCallback{ heartbeatLostCallback }
        {}

        ~HeartbeatController() = default;

        HeartbeatController(HeartbeatController &&other) :
            heartbeatLostCallback{ std::move(other.heartbeatLostCallback) },
            loopThread{ std::move(other.loopThread) },
            lastBeat{ std::move(other.lastBeat) },
            panicTime{ std::move(other.panicTime) },
            checkDuration{ std::move(other.checkDuration) }
        {}

        HeartbeatController& operator=(HeartbeatController &&other)
        {
            heartbeatLostCallback = std::move(other.heartbeatLostCallback);
            loopThread = std::move(other.loopThread);
            lastBeat = std::move(other.lastBeat);
            panicTime = std::move(other.panicTime);
            checkDuration = std::move(other.checkDuration);

            return *this;
        }

        HeartbeatController(const HeartbeatController&) = delete;
        HeartbeatController& operator=(const HeartbeatController&) = delete;

        void interrupt() noexcept
        {
            interrupted = true;
        }

        void beat() noexcept
        {
            lastBeat = Clock::now();
        }

        void start()
        {
            auto loop = [this]
            {
                while (!interrupted)
                {
                    if (Clock::now() - lastBeat > panicTime)
                        heartbeatLostCallback(); //here you can insert some your code which you wanna execute after no beat() for panicTime duration

                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(checkDuration);
                }
            };

            lastBeat = Clock::now();

            loopThread = std::thread{ loop };
        }

    private:
        using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;

        std::reference_wrapper<std::function<void()>> heartbeatLostCallback;
        std::thread loopThread;

        std::chrono::time_point<Clock> lastBeat;
        std::chrono::milliseconds panicTime;
        std::chrono::milliseconds checkDuration;

        bool interrupted = false;
    };
```